# Clone external hard drive without leaving a record on the drive itself?

Tags: windows-7, macos, external-hard-drive, clone

I have an external hard drive which I need to make an exact copy of, but I need to do so without leaving any trace of the operation  on the original drive.

I'm primarily a Mac user, but I suspect the drive in question is formatted in FAT32, so if it would be easier to perform the operation in question, I have a Windows 7 platform as well.

My first question is, if I simply connect the external drive to my computer to check which file system is used on the drive, will this leave a record on the drive?

Second, what would be the best method of making a clone of this drive without leaving any sort of record on the drive itself? I was thinking originally of using Mac's Disk Utility to make a Disk Image of the drive. Would this work, or do you have a better suggestion using either Mac OS 10.7, or Windows 7?

NOTE: I should mention that I strongly doubt the Hard Drive in question will be subjected to any serious examination by professionals. I am more curious if the cloning would be evident to an average person using the tools available to them in either Mac OS X, or Windows 7?

Comment: Some specialised „data recovery” live-cd linuxes do not mount the disks when connected.

Comment: @kinokijuf - Can this solution work on Mac OS X?

Comment: I did not tell you of any solution.

Comment: Or you can use specialist (expensive) forensic kits.

Comment: @kinokijuf - Ok, so what you're saying is that with Disk Utility, what I am asking is not possible? I doubt the hard drive in question will be subjected to any serious forensic examination. I'm more curious if the operation would be evident to any of the layperson tools available on the mentioned operating systems?

Comment: I'm curious, but I think dd should work just fine. Just a liveCD/USB of just about any linux distro, and use dd. I'll test this later with a flash drive at home, but I'm betting doing a byte for byte transfer won't change anything on the original while giving you an exact copy. It'll take forever for any large device, though.

Comment: @Rob - Im curious as well. Please do let me know what the outcome of your test is. And Im assuming I can run said operation on my Mac? I actually don't think there is a lot of data on the drive in question. I haven't actually looked at it yet as I'm worried even plugging it in and looking at the data will leave a record. Do you think it's safe to plug it in and take a look at what's on it size wise? Please refer to my "Note" on the question as it explains the scope of my concern.

Comment: I'm not positive if OS X has dd or not, I've never worked with it. I'll definitely do some tests with dd and gparted. I've got a feeling gparted won't leave any obvious records, either. Should be able to let you know what I find in about an hour and a half.

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to do this often (or are you rich)? There are hardware utilities that allow you to connect hard drives with write blockers between them, preventing absolutely any write operations on the HDD itself (at least those that might be initiated by your computer - the firmware of the HDD will still probably update internal values such as power on count and other SMART parameters). They are quite expensive for one-time use.

You don't need to be a professional to see these values - if you're paranoid and looking for it, you would notice.

Apart from that something like `clonezilla` is a nice free HDD cloning tool that should make things simple and safe. IF you want to pay, try Acronis TrueImage or Symantec GHOST.

Answer (score 1):

Symantec/Norton GHOST would allow you to do this on a  Windows 7 system. It allows a "cold" image so there should be no trace on the external drive.

Comment: I'd recommend using one of several backup utilities from Hiren's Boot CD (Free) http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/

Comment: @Dave M - Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure if you read the "Note" I added to the question just a moment ago, but it explains that I doubt there will be any examination of the drive by a professional. I am looking for a method that will allow the clone to not be evident to a layperson using the tools available to them, i.e. examining when the last time the file was viewed for example (if you can think of any others...). I say this because if possible, I would like to stick with tools I currently have access to, and Norton is not one of them. Would Disk Utility leave a trail?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that mounting a disk read/write could leave traces.  On the Mac, you can use `mount(8)` or `diskutil(8)` to mount a disk read-only.  But off the top of my head, I don't know how to get the Mac to not automount any new disk you attach.  So the problem is getting the Mac to not automount it, so that you can then mount it read-only by hand.